# Crystal report parametr field validation

Tags: crystal-reports

Im using crystal report in asp.net....I have create parameter fields to get input....Consider if i create numeric parametere field then i have to validate that particular field if user enter other than numbers  how?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate parameter value before pass it to report and if its value was not valid show a message and don't preview report.

Comment: how can i validate crystal parametres field? any options?