# Crystal report (required field validation)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Im using asp.net crystal report(not in crystal report XI)

i just create parameter field datatype(string) and add some default values from the table

If user didint select  any value and press submit then nothing record(s) has been fetched...

so if user press submit without selecting any record i have to show message to user to select  records...(required field validate)

how in crystal report?

Comment: Domnic, instead of opening multiple questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004634/crystal-report-parametr-field-validation), you may wish to edit the original to provide more information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you strictly relying on CR's parameter prompt, or are you prompting for the parameter yourself on a form you created?

You really should be checking the value the user selects within your ASP.NET code before passing it on to the report.  Besides simply checking to see if the user chose something, this way you could check for other problems in the user input before passing the data on to your report.